# Vectors of a complex type

Tags: xsd

Is there a way to define the cardinality of a type at the place where that type is referenced?

```
<xs:complexType name="xyType">
  <xs:element name="xy" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                        ...
                    </xs:choice>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
```

So for instance I have two types A and B that have elements that reference this type, but in one case I only allow one xy (like above) and another I would like to allow multiple xy (like if I change the maxOccurs above for xy to "unbounded").

I don't want to have to completely separate complexType definitions for xyType (single) and xyType (unbounded), because in reality the definition for this type is very long and complex.

If possible I would also like to not define too many types (like separating the inner complexType from the body and having two types referencing that type). This would also be very complex in my specific scenario (I have a complex class hierarchy that I try to define with a schema, so everything is bloated already).

So basically I'm looking for something where the type that is referencing this type is taking care about the cardinality if that makes sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you modularize the parts of `xyType` as best as possible for sharing across two types, say `xyType_A` that allows only one `xy` and `xyType_B` that allows an unbounded number of `xy`s.  (Of course choose semantically appropriate names rather than these stand-ins.)

For example, `xyType_A` and `xyType_B` could differ in their definitions of `xy`'s cardinality yet share the complex machinery defined in `commonType`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="xyType_A">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="xy"  type="commonType" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="xyType_B">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="xy"  type="commonType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="commonType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <!-- further complicated structures continue here -->
        </xs:choice>
        <!-- and here or wherever -->
     </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

The principle (if not the magnitude of opportunity) would be the same if the elements of varying cardinality are deeper in the definitional hierarchy: Factor as much of the common definitional components as possible, and reuse those in the distinctly defined types.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work in XSD 1.0. You could use Schematron (on top of the XSD 1.0); it would work with no issues.

It is possible in XSD 1.1. It would require a bit of work, at least based on my understanding. The solution is to use assertions; however, they seem to be supported for complex and simple types only, which means you may still need to introduce two new types specific to element A and B; however, they would simply be extending xyType (100% reuse), for the purpose of providing a place to define the assertion specific to A and B.

If you're interested in either alternative, tag the question appropriately.